# Do I need to renew my carte de séjour if I left France for over a year?

Tags: visa

I hold a carte de séjour that expires in October 2019. I left with my husband (he's French) to China for a year now and we are planning to go back to France this year. Does anyone here know if my card is still valid or do have to renew my card, since I left France for a year already?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's the validity of your carte de séjour ?

Comment: @dda does your comment seek information that is absent from the clause "that expires in October 2019"?  If so, what information does it seek?

Comment: @phoog I was pointing out the obvious...

Comment: I received the card last year and it is valid for 2 years.  Will expire in October 2019. I don't know if there's a rule  " if exit France for more than 6months so and so.. " the validity is gone.

Comment: @dda many countries provide for the automatic invalidation of residence documents after a period of absence of a certain length, regardless of the nominal validity, so pointing out the obvious here is just confusing.

Comment: @Kll there's no such rule. Besides, the préfectures are too busy emitting the cartes de séjour to even have the time to check on people's presence.

Comment: @dda that's good to know and thanks so much for the info. I have been searching everywhere online.

Comment: @dda do you have a reference for that?  I have read the contrary, that an absence of six months or more invalidates the carte de séjour, at least for certain types.  I will post an answer as soon as I find a reference, but I'm traveling today so that might not be very soon.

Comment: @phoog personal experience (but my SO's cds was a 10-year card, although I don't think that matters).

Comment: Triple confirmation would be very helpful Thank you all for your help.